# Not getting grouping,newspaper, grid layout in kubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux

I have installed kubuntu 15.04 on dell inspiron 5000 series laptop with plasma. I am getting only folder and desktop option in desktop layout. even after installing ked-plasma-containments-addon.